# How to build an installer with sbt

Tags: scala, installation, sbt, graalvm-native-image

I am currently having a Graalvm native image executable, and I need to build an installer that would ask users to provide an installation location, copy the native image executable to the location, and write a registry.

What would be the best approach to do this? My first idea was to look for a specific SBT plugin, but I can't find any.

Comment: Did you look at sbt-native-packager? (I don't know if it meets your requirements, but it's the best known thing in this general space.)

Comment: I did, and it looks like I can even provide a custom wix XML in order to make the installer. It looks like it might be the best option right now. Thanks